# I have a problem with Django database. in model

Tags: django, database, django-models

I have specified that my bio and image fields can be empty, but why does it give me an error and say that I have to fill it in?[image]

```
class User_account(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    marital_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bio = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
    visitor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='profile_img')
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying [**`null=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) does not mean the field is not required. `null=True` has only impact on the database: it makes the field NULLable. You should use [**`blank=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank) to make the field not required:

```
class User_account(models.Model):
    # …
    bio = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    # …
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`User_account`</s> to `UserAccount`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the field nullable in the database?

Comment: @aprogrammer: databases often allow a field to be NULLable: it means that you can store NULL in it, besides the other valid values. But that does not mean that the model forms mark it as optional (although the combination of `null=True` and `blank=True` is quite common). `blank=True` deals with the form, and thus makes the *form* field optional.

Comment: I want to know what is the use application of null?

Comment: @aprogrammer: the programmer can freely choose this. Often it is used for *not applicable*, *not known*, etc. It also propagates in functions, for example `NULL + 42` is `NULL`. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)